# Is there a limit to the number of addresses that you can pass in an array as an argument to a function?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I'm trying to create a simple airdrop contract. I'm fairly experienced with Solidity, so this is not a completely noob question - but maybe I'm missing something.

My airdrop contract has a function that accepts an array of addresses

```
 function bulkWhitelist
    (
        address[] calldata _to,
        address _projectAddress,
        string calldata _projectName
    )
    public onlyRole(WHITELISTER_ROLE) {
        for (uint256 i=0; i<_to.length; i++) {
            whitelist[_to[i]] = true;
        }
        emit BulkWhitelist(_to, _projectAddress, _projectName, block.timestamp);
    }
```

Simple, I know, but I would like to keep the architecture as simple as possible.

Everything works well if I pass around 650 addresses or less to the contract as an array, but if I try to add more, I get a transaction block gas limit error. The problem is, increasing the block gas limit makes no difference - after around 650 addresses, the error always comes up with a number above the current gas limit, no matter how much I raise it.

The error also comes up if I remove the for loop from the contract - so it doesn't seem to be a gas limit per se.

I am using hardhat and I haven't deployed to a testnet to see if I still get the error - so it may be a hardhat limitation. I'll try that later, but until I get to doing it, the question is: Does anyone know of any inherent limitation in Solidity that will limit the amount of addresses that I can pass within an array as a function argument? I can't find anything online, bar the well-known 'maximum 16 arguments' limit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The block gas limit is the upper limit for a block and it is a constant. You cannot have a transaction that consumes a limit that is more than the block gas limit.

If you want to do a batch transfer, then I would suggest you to break the number fo addresses into smaller chunks, loop through the chunks and pass the batch as an array into the smart contract.